# Single SELECT combining multiple JOINs

Tags: select, join

I'm trying to figure out how to write a SQL query that returns the result of two other SELECT statements, each with their own JOIN. Here's the scenario:

Table1 might have NULL values in the T1Number and/or T1State columns. Table2 might have rows with a matching number or state. I want all rows from Table1, but want to fill in any NULL T1Number with T2Number when the states match, and fill in any NULL T1State with T2State when the numbers match. I don't want rows from Table2 that don't have a matching state or number:

```
Table1:                         Table2:

Name  T1Number  T1State         T2Number  T2State
----  --------  -------         --------  -----
Joe   1         NULL            1         MA
Bob   NULL      CA              2         CA
Dan   NULL      NULL            3         FL
Sam   4         NY              4         NY
Ray   5         TX              8         PA
```

So I have one SELECT statement to get the Number:

```
SELECT 
  Table1.Name,
  Table1.T1Number,
  Table1.T1State,
  Table2.T2Number,
  Table2.T2State
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.T2State = Table1.T1State
WHERE (Table1.T1Number IS NULL OR Table1.T1State IS NULL)

Result:

Name  T1Number  T1State  T2Number  T2State
----  --------  -------  --------  -------     
Bob   NULL      CA       2         CA
```

And another SELECT statement to get the State:

```
SELECT
  Table1.Name,
  Table1.T1Number,
  Table1.T1State
  Table2.T2Number
  Table2.T2State
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.T2Number = Table1.T1Number
WHERE (Table1.T1Number IS NULL OR Table1.T1State IS NULL)

Result:

Name  T1Number  T1State  T2Number  T2State
----  --------  -------  --------  -------     
Joe   1         NULL     1         MA
```

How do I write a combined SELECT statement that gives me the following desired result?

```
Name  Number  State
----  ------  -----     
Joe   1       MA 
Bob   2       CA
Dan   NULL    NULL
Sam   4       NY
Ray   5       TX
```

I assume I need a containing SELECT statement that does a LEFT JOIN between Table1 and the union of the above queries, but I know this is way easier than I'm making it. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single `select` statement without the `where` clause and a `case` statement in your `join` operation. Something like:

```
SELECT t1.Name
     , CASE WHEN t1.Number is null then t2.Number else t1.Number END as Number
     , CASE WHEN t1.State is null then t2.State else t1.State end as State
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 
ON CASE WHEN t1.Number is null THEN t1.State 
        ELSE CONVERT(varchar(1), t1.Number) END
    = CASE WHEN t1.Number is null THEN tab2.State 
           ELSE CONVERT(varchar(1), t2.Number) END
```